# Kentico - Import Toolkit XML to Custom Page Type

Tags: kentico

I have an xml and want to import to Kentico 9 as Custom Page type items. Is this possible? I don't have access to the Import Tool Kit and will need to ask someone else to do it, so want to make sure it's doable.

From what I read here https://docs.kentico.com/k9/external-utilities/kentico-import-toolkit, I saw the mention of Pages, but not sure if it includes Custom Page Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can import to almost any object, including custom page types, within Kentico using a flat file, xml, Excel or another database connection.